# Extending SNMP IF-MIB with custom data

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I've a system where several specific NIC cards do not pass to the kernel traffic counters (DPDK cards) so I cannot use SNMP IF-MIB to get usage information. But, I've a system command that provides that counters so I'd like to expose them over SNMP using exec/pass/override.

I'm a bit confused. I'd like this to be transparent, so I should override oids for IfInOctets, IfOutOctets etc, for the specific interface:

- As far as I know neither override or extend can achieve this (they either statically override an existing OID or dynamically create a new OID in the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.

So, the solution seems to use pass_persist. IF-MIB index may change on reboot, due to the order linux loads the driver modules so it's this a safe solution? Can I create a pass_persist script that always adds my counters to the, for example, ueth1 index, even if it changes?

Thanks a lot in advance.